# MVC - bootstrap datetimepicker control reset after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have datetimepicker control on MVC form. and there is situation where I submit the form and after submit, I add custom validation error message from controller and postback the form.  but when form reloads with error message then all the fields in form retains value except datetimepicker control. datetimepicker control becomes empty. what could be issue?

below is code -

cshtml -

```
 <div class='input-group date col-xs-3' id='datetimepicker1' style="float: left">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control dobinit required", @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY  *"} })
       <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
  </div>
```

javascript code at initial stage to set default value -

```
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                        format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
                        minDate: "01/01/1900",
                        maxDate: "@today"
                    });
```

Comment: You have to dynamically set the value: $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('update', 'modelvalue');. Maybe inside document ready, check if there is a value in the model property.

Comment: @GHDevOps its solved my problem. but why it is clearing datetimepicker value after postback.

Comment: It's stateless and your helpers can't set the value for the control like they're doing for the other controls. You have to manually set it. Same goes for dropdowns.